# Azure automated data uploading of lookup table/data

Tags: azure, csv, automation, azure-data-lake

I have a set of csv files or lookup tables which are manually updated by the business users. Right now the users are sending the updated data via email and I upload these files to datalake via storage explorer.

Business users don't have access to upload the data to datalake directly using storage explorer and hence I am looking for some options for them to upload easily.

I need these files to be uploaded to data lake for ETL process.

I am looking for some options to automating this process. Is there any space like one drive or sharepoint and hence datafactory can be connected to extract these csv to datalake. Please throw some light. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can use Azure blob storage for this. Check this Microsoft doc for the process to move them to Datalake - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-copy-data-azure-storage-blob.

Krish

Comment: Thanks Krish. I have updated my question now. The business users dont have access to upload to Azure blob or datalake directly using storage explorer. Hence looking for easy option for them to upload.

Comment: Ok, easiest is to create a blob storage and give them access, but if it's difficult and they already have access to Onedrive, you can create a logic app or an Azure function to move them. Logic app needs less coding but function apps are lot flexible.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-onedrive shows how to work with one drive using logic apps. I haven't tried it but positive that you can write them to blob storage too using a logic app, have  a look.

Comment: Just to complete the above comment, I had a quick look and there is a connector to blob, and it is extremely easy to develop a logic app to do this - just two steps in the app.